# Convert image to pdf php

Tags: php, image, pdf

I am using [csxi](http://www.chestysoft.com/ximage/twainupload.asp) to make scanning for documnets as image, but I have to upload pdf files to server. How can I convert image to PDF in php ? or is there any way to make csxi scan documents as PDF not image

Comment: ImageMagick can read and write PDF files, as well as other images.

Comment: Do  you have a clear demo for using Imagic??

Comment: `shell_exec('convert /path/to/input.png /path/to/output.pdf')` does the trick if your server is properly configured - Imagick is installed, GhostScript is installed, php is allowed to execute shell commands, etc.

Comment: This command is not allowed on server.

Comment: Then you should still be able to run an equivalent command through the imagick php extension - open the image file, save it as a pdf, done.

Comment: You could use online PDF service http://www.convertapi.com/

Answer (score 4):

If you have ImageMagick installed on your machine you could use the [ImageMagick bindings for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) to execute some simple PHP code to do this task:

```
$im=new Imagick('my.png');
$im->setImageFormat('pdf');
$im->writeImage('my.pdf');
```

Alternatively if you don't have ImageMagick available you could use a commercial API such as [Zamzar](https://developers.zamzar.com/) which supports image to PDF conversion via PHP (more info [in the docs](https://developers.zamzar.com/docs#section-Start_a_conversion_job)).

Code to use this would be:

```
<?php
// Build request
$endpoint = "https://api.zamzar.com/v1/jobs";
$apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
$sourceFilePath = "my.png";
$targetFormat = "pdf";

$sourceFile = curl_file_create($sourceFilePath);    
$postData = array(
  "source_file" => $sourceFile,
  "target_format" => $targetFormat
);

// Send request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiKey . ":");
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Process response (with link to converted files)
$response = json_decode($body, true);
print_r($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your image inside `HTML` and use some `HTML to PDF converter` like `fpdf` or `mpdf`

Comment: The image is sent to CSXI buffer and sent to php server.. so I cant wrap the image inside the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Here, Php 7.4, Laravel 7+, ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16, and Ghostscript gs10.00.0 is used.
If any files are contained in the folder JpgToPdf then delete them. And so on.

```
/**
     * jpg To pdf WEB
     *
     * @method convertJpgToPdf
     */
    public function convertJpgToPdf(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            //get list of files
            $files = Storage::files('JpgToPdf');

            /*get count of files and , 
            * check if any files contain
            * if any files contains
            * then
            * get the files name
            * delete one by one 
            */
            if(count($files) >1 )
            {
                foreach($files as $key => $value)
                {
                    //get the file name
                    $file_name = basename($value);

                    //delete file from the folder
                    File::delete(storage_path('app/JpgToPdf/'. $file_name));
                }
            }

            if ($request->has('jpeg_file')) 
            {
                $getPdfFile = $request->file('jpeg_file');

                $originalname = $getPdfFile->getClientOriginalName();

                $path = $getPdfFile->storeAs('JpgToPdf', $originalname);
            }

            // file name without extension
            $filename_without_ext = pathinfo($originalname, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            //get the upload file
            $storagePath = storage_path('app/JpgToPdf/' . $originalname);

            $imagick = new Imagick();

            $imagick->setResolution(300, 300);
            
            $imagick->readImage($storagePath);

            $imagick->setImageCompressionQuality( 100 );

            $imagick->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);

            $imagick->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);

            $imagick->writeImage( storage_path('app/JpgToPdf/') . $filename_without_ext .'.pdf' );

            return response()->download(storage_path('app/JpgToPdf/') . $filename_without_ext .'.pdf' );
        
        } catch (CustomModelNotFoundException $exception) {
            // Throws error exception
            return $exception->render();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use convertapi service, easy to install:

```
composer require convertapi/convertapi-php
```

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use \ConvertApi\ConvertApi;

//get api key: https://www.convertapi.com/a/si
ConvertApi::setApiSecret('xxx');

$result = ConvertApi::convert('pdf', ['File' => '/dir/test.png']);

# save to file
$result->getFile()->save('/dir/file.pdf');
```

to convert multiple files and other options check https://github.com/ConvertAPI/convertapi-php

Answer (score -3):

For just a few images, do it manually and easily with the Chrome web browser.  You wont need an internet connection.

1. Save the following with `.html` extension in the same folder of your image:

> ```
> <html>
>  <body>
>  <img src="image.jpg" width="100%">
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

2. Open the html file with Google Chrome,
3. Crtl + P, to open the print dialog
4. Choose Save as PDF, to save it locally
5. Alternatively, you could send a copy to your smatphone via Google Cloud Print