# PHP how to use ImageMagick convert in php

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have a php site where I create a pdf book with the ImageMagick command convert dynamically from some pictures and offer it to download.

```
`convert *.img eBook.pdf`
```

because of Traffic reasons I needed to move the site to a provider, who restricts bash commands. As feared also `system()` `exec()` `passthru()` `shell_exec()` are somehow restricted. I tried to see if they are disabled with `echo ini_get("disable_functions");` But this don't react in any way.

So I tried to see if the commands are disabled with `function_exists` but I got TRUE. They are enabled.
So the functions exist but they are somehow not working.

I have seen that the php has the module ImageMagick loaded and enabled. So now my question is if it is possible to do the above commands without using bash?

or is there another way or workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert image to pdf php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385325/convert-image-to-pdf-php)

Answer (score 1):

> I have seen that the php has the module ImageMagick loaded and enabled.

I assume this is Imagick and that is an API for Imagemagick. This uses code which will allow you to run Imagemagick in "Safe mode".

It is a little bit quicker and suposidly safer than running Imagemagick directly but I think a little bit harder to use with less options.

I personally do no use it but looking for Imagick is a start.

Example of some code copied from https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.appendimages.php :

```
$im1 = new Imagick();   
$im1->readImage('multi-page-pdf.pdf'); 
$im1->resetIterator(); 
// Combine multiple images into one, stacked vertically. 
$ima = $im1->appendImages(true); 
$ima->setImageFormat("png"); 
header("Content-Type: image/png"); 
echo $ima;
```

Comment: The author of the question wants the opposite of your answer.